# Socket.io in express receives undefined data from the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm working on this simple tic-tac-toe app and whenever a player hits a button it will trigger the function **markTheCell(button)** passing the button's id. This function then emits the player which is string value and the button id to the server. I put console log in the client page to see whether a valid value is being passed and it is. But when I tried to log it in the server the value of the player become object Object and the button id is undefined. I don't know if I failed how to put and use the parameters correctly. Hope someone lend a help because I'm stuck with this.

**index.html**

```
<body>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 jumbotron">
            <h4>You are player <span id="name"></span></h4>
            <button id="one" onclick="markTheCell(this.id)" class="btn btn-default"></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button></br>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button></br>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        var player = "";
        $(document).ready(function () {

            socket.on('player', function (playerNo) {
                player = playerNo;
                $('#name').text(playerNo);
            });

            socket.on('hitAMark', function (player, button) {
                console.log("in client hit a mark player "+ player);
                 console.log("in client hit a mark button "+ button);
                $(button).text(player);
            });
        })
        function markTheCell(button) {
            socket.emit('mark', {player,button });
             console.log("in markTheCell client hit a mark player "+ player);
                 console.log("in markTheCell client hit a mark button "+ button);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
var player = 0;
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    if(player==0){
        player++;
        socket.emit('player', "X");
        console.log("Player "+ player +" is connected");
    }else if(player==1){
         player++;
        socket.emit('player', "O");
        console.log("Player "+ player +" is connected");
    }

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('A user is disconnected');
    });


    socket.on('mark', function(player, button){
        console.log("in server hit a mark button "+ player);
          console.log("in server hit a mark player "+button);

        io.emit('hitAMark', {player,button});
    });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server is listening on port 3000!');
});
```

The screenshot of the console in browser and cmd:
[image]

[image]

Comment: [object Object] usually means you're trying to print an object as a string. Try using JSON.parse() after receiving the object to convert it from a string to an Object

Comment: In the console.log on the server there is a text button and variable player and vice versa. a small mix up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try emitting `{player:player,button:button}` instead of `{player,button}`. May be it can work.